# Auto login boot camp partition in VMWare Fusion?

Tags: bootcamp, virtualization, vmware

My VMWare Fusion is set up to use a Boot Camp partition. Is there any way to have it automatically login to a user account when the virtual machine starts up, but still require a password when booting via Boot Camp?

The reason I ask is because when launching VMWare Fusion in unity mode, you always have to interact with the machine the first time it logs on. It would be nice if you can just run an application from the VMWare Fusion menu, and have it seamlessly startup the virtual machine, login, and launch the application without any interaction required.

Answer (score 2):

As the auto-login or password is in Windows, and Windows doesn't know if it is booted via BootCamp or VMWare, I don't think you can do this from the Windows side.

It doesn't seem likely, but perhaps you can set it to always require password, but then use AppleScript and VMWare, or Automator GUI Scripting, to enter the password for you.